# How to avoid "sausage" type binding when having nested model

Tags: angularjs

I have nested model and I am trying to avoid `vm.someObject.someChild.ChildOfChild.name` type of situations. Is there a way to set the model for outer `<div>` so that I can instead do ChildOfChild.name or even name. In Silverlight this was called DataContext. I put "vm" on the $scope, but in html I would like to avoid having to type the full path to attribute.

For example:

```
 <div>
    {{someObject.Id}}
    <div>
        {{someObject.name.first}}
        {{someObject.name.last}}
    </div>
     <div>
            {{someObject.someChild.name.first}}
     </div>
 </div>
```

I would like to do something like this

```
  <div datacontext = someObject>
    {{Id}}
    <div datacontext = name>
        {{first}}
        {{last}}
    </div>
     <div datacontext = someChild.name>
            {{first}}
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think we need some more detail. Can you post the template you're using?

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit. I've seen this question, or ones like it before, and I've also seen a similar solution in practice. I recommend against it, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a custom directive.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
  <div>
      Access from deepObj: {{ctrl.deepObj.one.two.three.four}}
  </div>
  <div scope-context="ctrl.deepObj.one.two.three">
      Access from third level: {{four}}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

var myCtrl = function() {
    this.deepObj = {one: {two: {three: {four: "value"}}}};
};

myApp.directive('scopeContext', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope: true,
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var scopeContext = scope.$eval(attrs.scopeContext);
            angular.extend(scope, scopeContext);
        }
    };
});
```

See the documentation on [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-scope-) for information on what `scope: true` does.

Make sure you don't call the directive something like `data-context` as an attribute starting with `data-` has a special meaning in HTML5.

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rMUQlaNsH8RTWiRrmohx?p=preview

Note that this can break two-way bindings for primitive values on the scope context. See this plunker for an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/lCuNMxVaLY4l4k5tzHAn?p=preview

Comment: Hey @rob, I wanted to say that i like the effort you've put into this answer, and I hope you don't think my answer below is panning your work. I've seen something like this put into practice in an Angular application and it had nightmarish effects.  So my answer recommends against it.

Comment: That said, this answer can work really well, but only in very, very careful hands.

Comment: @blesh - Yeah you raise some valid issues. Since the benefit of this is pretty small I'm not sure if I would actually use this solution

Answer (score 2):

### You could try/abuse ng-init

Try `ng-init`, you'll have *one* more `.`, but it's better than the other answer I've seen proposed:

```
<div ng-init="x = foo.bar.baz">
   {{x.id}}
   {{x.name}}
</div>
```

*BUT* Be warned, doing this actually creates a value on your scope, so doing this with something like `ng-model` if you're reusing the same name, or in a repeater, will produce unexpected results.

### Why a custom directive for this probably isn't a good idea

What @rob suggests above is clever, and I've seen it suggested before. But there are issues, which he touches on, in part at least:

1. **Scope complexity:** Adding n-scopes that need to be created (with prototypical inheritence) whenever views are compiled.
2. **View processing complexity:** Adding an additional directive (again for no real *functional* benefit) that needs to be checked on each node when the view is compiled.*
3. **Readability?** The next Angular developer will likely *less* readable because it's different.
4. **Forms Validation:** If you're doing anything with forms in Angular, this might break things like validation.
5. **ng-model woahs**: Setting things with `ng-model` this way will not be at all intuitive. You'll have to use `$parent.whatever` or `$parent.$parent.whatever` depending on how may contexts deep you are.

* For reference, views are $compiled more than you think: For every item in a repeater, whenever it's changed for example.

### A common idea that just doesn't jive with Angular

I feel like this question comes up frequently in StackOverflow, but I'm unable to find other similar questions ATM.  ... regardless, if you look at the approaches above, and the warnings given about what the side effects will be, you should be able to discern it's probably not a good idea to do what you're trying to do just for the sake of readability.